# Android: click event on game object

Tags: android

I'm creating a game for Android and i want to add click event on some game objects/images in my game. The problem is that the object/images is created programatically in a Thread, so i don't know how to add a click event to them. My code structur looks like this:

-> Main.xml

-> Main.class

--> MainView.class

---> MainThread.class

And the objects is created in the MainThread class. How would i add click event to them?

Im create the object like this, in MainThread class:

```
protected Bitmap image;
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resources.getIdentifier(filename, "drawable", "com.example.android.jetboy"));
```

Comment: How are you creating these image objects? What kind of objects are they - are they Views?

Comment: Please post the code that adds these objects to the user interface.

Comment: I posted the object creation code, thanks for the tip.